# How to swap in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set like below and i want to swap if a value in one variable is greater than the other.

data

```
   start_year   end_year
    1991         1995
    1994         1990
    1997         1999
    1994         1995
    1995         1995
    1996         1991
```

I want to swap the rows where `start_year` is greater than `end_year`.

Expected output:

```
   start_year   end_year
    1991         1995
    1990         1994
    1997         1999
    1994         1995
    1995         1995
    1991         1996
```

Tried:

```
data_created = if(data$start_year > data$end_year, data$start_year == data$end_year & 
   data$end_year == data$start_year, data$start_year == data$start_year & 
   data$end_year == data$end_year)
```

Please help me in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `?pmax` and `?pmin` to compute the elementwise maximum and minimum of the years. Combined with `transfrom`, this would be:

```
transform(df, 
  start_year = pmin(start_year, end_year), 
  end_year = pmax(start_year, end_year))
#  start_year end_year
#1       1991     1995
#2       1990     1994
#3       1997     1999
#4       1994     1995
#5       1995     1995
#6       1991     1996
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` and `sort` for this.

put:

```
t(apply(df, 1, sort))
```

This will sort the data row by row (the `1` argument in `apply` means "by rows").

Comment: This will get nasty if other columns are present, especially when those are not `numeric` since `apply` converts `data.frame`s to `matrix` class

Comment: Easy enough to isolate the columns with `df[, c("start_year", "end_year")]` and then `cbind` them back in.  Or perhaps even just change those columns as a subset with one line.